# Image processing with lossy compression

Tags: image-processing, lossless-compression, lossy-compression

If we compare image procesing of the losslessly compressed images with the image processing of the lossy compressed images, does the latter provide the results comparable to the former one.

I am asking this question because the images prodiced  by lossless compression are ok for human eye but they vary at minute details which may effect the processing of images by the computer. But I can't tell how much.

Comment: You probably mean "lossy" instead of "lossless" in the second paragraph. And the general answer is that it all depends on the compression ratio that you impose to the compressor and on the perceptual model that used when defining the lossy compressed format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see much of a question here, but you are right. It is especially visible if processing a JPG image with a medium compression ratio -- the 8x8 squares of which JPG's are built of tend to get more visible after filtering.

This is comparable to the rising of computational error when operating on computer-based floating point numbers.

Your best bet for image processing is using lossless formats for image processing -- PNG's are a good choice, cause they both provide lossless compression, as well as a decent support for bitdepths, transparency and are browser-compatible.

Another format, more often used in the professional world are TIFF's (Targa).

However, note that if your **source** image is already in a loss-based format, converting it to a lossless one will only prevent adding additional artifact's, not spreading and enhancing the old one. You can however reduce the extent of error by converting it to a lossless format and running it through a small seed gaussian blur.

Comment: I'm not sure the floating-point imagery is an accurate description. In lossy compression, specific information is voluntarily discarded because it is thought not to matter (much) to the *human* experience of the data.

Comment: I was more comparing it to the way that rounding errors tend to build up over operations. It's a very simplified imagery :>

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for the [Perceptual Image Diff](http://pdiff.sourceforge.net/) utility?